# SHould I trust BLAS libraries unconditionally to improve performance

Tags: blas

I am working on some project that involves computationally intensive image processing algorithms that involve a lot of steps that could be handled by BLAS libraries (mostly level 1 routines). Since my data is quite large it certainly makes sense to consider using BLAS.

I have seen examples where optimised BLAS libraries offer a tremendous increase in performance (factor 10 in speedup for matrix matrix multiplications are nothing unusual).

Should I apply the BLAS functions whenever possible and trust it blindly that it will yield a better performance or should I do a case by case analysis and only apply BLAS where it is necessary?

Blindly applying BLAS has the benefit that I save some time now since I don't have to profile my code in detail. On the other hand, carefully analysing each method might give me the best possible performance but I wonder if it is worth spending a few hours now just to gain half a second later when running the software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A while agon, I read in a book: (1) Golden rule about optimization: don't do it (2) Golden rule about optimization (for experts only): don't do it yet. In short, I'd recommend to proceed as follows:

- step 1: implement the algorithms in the simplest / most legible way
- step 2: measure performances
- step 3: if (and only if) performances are not satisfactory, use a profiler to detect the hot spots. They are often not where we think !!
- step 4: try different alternatives for the hot spots only (measure performances for each alternative)

More speficically about your question: yes, a good implementation of BLAS can make some difference (it may use AVX instruction sets, and for matrix times matrix multiply, decompose the matrix into blocs in a way that is more cache-friendly), but again, I would not "trust unconditionally" (depends on the version of BLAS, on the data, on the target machine etc...), then *measuring* performances and *comparing* is absolutely necessary.